# How did Pythagoras argue for the Pythagorean theorem?

Tags: geometry

There are lots of proofs for the Pythagorean theorem. But, how did Pyhtagoras argue for the theorem himself?

Comment: You can post this question in "history of science and4 mathematics" in stack to get a better answer

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I was wondering myself if it was the right forum to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem#Pythagorean_proof), he used a proof calculating the same area twice (after rearranging). He almost certainly didn't use $a, b, c$, though, but rather words and drawings.

Comment: What evidence is there for that ? Pythagoras did not leave any writings, his society was secretive and we know little in general about him.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus I don't know. Ask Wikipedia.

Comment: No. It's not my answer.

Comment: I am reporting what wikipedia said, and to me it seems a most reasonable possibility. Why aren't you venting your "we can't really know" scepticism in an answer of your own? And also, I have not claimed that this is truth. I have claimed that wikipedia claims that this might be truth, and the proof of that is found just by clicking the link in my answer, so I don't know why you're really taking it out on me and my answer at all.

Comment: I am not answering this question exactly for the reasons I gave. I feel that your answer is misleading, sorry. Its really a question about ancient history, OP might think about asking it on a history exchange, they may be more informed there, and I would be interested in reading the responses. (although in general I support this type of question on MSE)